# Retrieve dependent rowset from a rowset (not a single row) in Zend framework

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, frameworks

I'm wondering if I can use the Zend framework to retrieve additional dependent rows efficiently without resorting to a lot of custom code. I'll use the Zend example of the Bugs database to translate to my problem:

```
$accountsTable = new Accounts();
$accountsRowset = $accountsTable->find(1234);
$user1234 = $accountsRowset->current();       
$bugsReportedByUser = $user1234->findDependentRowset('Bugs');
```

However, in my case the Bugs Table would have additional dependents, which in this example could be BugReproduction. How would one retrieve these Reproductions (which have a many-to-1-Bugs).
It seems like very poor coding to **foreach** over the **$bugsReportedByUser** and fetch additional dependentRowsets to get the Reproductions. This would result in 'n'-order queries, while one always wants a fixed number of queries per request.

This seems trivial with Joins, but I've not found a reasonable way to do so in the Zend ecosphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've thought long and hard, but it boils down to the fundamental missing of the rowset-method->getDependentRowset. (Not to be mistaken with a Row (singular)->getDepedentRowset() )

So extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abtract, and use it in the example's Bugs Table class by:

```
class BugsTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'bugs';
    protected $_rowsetClass = 'MyRowset';
...
```

And have findDependentRowset($dependentTable) implemented in MyRowSet. A highlevel implementation would be:

1. retrieve bugs primary keys as `$ids` (array).
2. call `bugsTable->find($ids)` (relation could be found by using Zend_Db_Table_Relationship)
3. You now have all dependent rows from a multiple of row**s**
4. optional: ReproductionMapper logic would map them to objects. BugsMapper logic can then add them to the highlevel Bugs Model (not the BugsTable )

Comment: Of course this is not as efficient as real joins, however this way the complexity order has gone from `O(n)` to `O(x)` where `n` = the size of the resultset and `x` = the amount of dependent relations. (`O(1)` =  1 query to the server)